# database table change shows all associated tables

Tags: mysql, database

in database, maybe one table(assume is tableA) associate multiple tables, so if change the structure of this table(tableA),e.g. delete one associated column, then all other associated tables need to do change.

hence is there a tool can show what other tables need to be changed if I modify the tableA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use for example MySQL Workbench -> Reverse Engineer to see how tables are connected to each other; that assumes that the database has proper primary and foreign keys.